# Location triggered alarm

Tags: applications, google-play-store, android-versions

Suppose you want to activate an alarm triggered once a certain location is reached. There exist something capable of this already on Samsung S9 for example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your definition of Location... However i believe what your lookin for is called geo fencing...

It's the idea of creating a fence, using GPS.

The most common uses are for Pet care, and House Arrest.

Are you looking for a Geo Fencing application ?